# How to sign a transaction send by contract

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I am trying to understand the basics behind signing an ethereum transaction.
I come across Gnosis's MultiSigWallet :

https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/MultiSigWallet.sol

In which, a modifier onlyWallet requires a transaction must be sent from the contract itself, but the transaction is signed by one of the owners of the contracts:

```
modifier onlyWallet() {
    require(msg.sender == address(this));
    _;
}
```

for functions like:

```
function replaceOwner(address owner, address newOwner)
    public
    onlyWallet
    ownerExists(owner)
    ownerDoesNotExist(newOwner)
{...}
```

I have successfully deployed the contracts on my testnet, and tried its functionalities using their dapp https://wallet.gnosis.pm/#/transactions

However, I cannot understand how a transaction is signed and sent to meet the onlyWallet requirement, since signing a transaction using metamask for example will cause the msg.sender to be my own wallet address.

If possible, an example of this ethereumjs-tx's functions would be much appreciated.

like:

```
const privateKey = Buffer.from('<private key 1>','hex');
const txParams = {
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(11),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(1000000000),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(300000),
    to: '<contract address>',
    value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei("1",'ether')),
    data: '0x00',
    chainId: 1
};
let tx = new EthTx(txParams);
tx.sign(tx.serialize().toString('hex');
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(`0x${tx.serialize().toString('hex')}`, 
   (error, data) => {
       if(!error) {
            console.log(data);
       }else console.log(error);
    }
);
```

Thank you very much

Comment: You would have to get the wallet to call itself, presumably via `executeTransaction` (once enough signers have confirmed the transaction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding and removing an owner follows the same rules as confirming any transactions from the `MultiSigWallet`. Assume the wallet was deployed with 3 EOA addresses as owners and requiring 2 confirmations for execution. For any regular transaction, say donate funds from the wallet to a `FundRaisingContract`, one of the owners would need to first call `submitTransaction()` passing in the address of `FundRaisingContract`, the amount of ether, and the hash for the donate function. After submission, you still need 1 of the other owners to `confirmTransaction` (the submitter is automatically confirmed). Once completed, now `executeTransaction` can be successfully run which will execute the call to `donate()` **from the `MultiSigWallet` address**.

That last part is what you're looking for to answer your question. To add an owner, repeat the example but use the `MultiSigWallet` address and the hash of the `addOwner` method. When one of the other owners confirms the transaction, `addOwner` will be called and it will pass the `onlyWallet` modifier check.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer I realize how this works. I was thinking something wrong in the first place. Your answer further clarified my question. Thank you very much